# Can't run vlock-cmatrixreloaded with acpid anymore, after switching to systemd

Tags: systemd, acpid

In the old days, I configured acpid to launch `vlock-cmatrixreloaded` when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, now it no longer works since systemd handles TTYs, I just got a screen flash when I press those keys.

The only way to invoke it is launch it manually from a tty or xterm, anyway to fix that?

**EDIT**

<kbd>Fn</kbd> is a standard function key (like shift) on laptops, and acpi_listen prints:

`button/screenlock SCRNLCK 00000080 00000000 K`

And in acpid's handler.sh:

```
button/screenlock)
    /usr/bin/vlock-cmatrixreloaded -ans
    ;;
```

[Download source code here](http://login.icu.uzh.ch/~archer/vlock-cmatrixreloaded-0.01.tar.gz)

Comment: What fn-f2 does? I mean, what `acpi_listen` prints, when your press it. Show acpi config, related to this.

Comment: @int updated question area

Comment: @int oops, I made a stupid mistake, `vlock` works, but I'm running vlock-cmatrixreloaded on my system

Comment: If vlock works, then it is better to check differences between vlock and vlock-cmatrixreloaded. You can ask maintaner of this package in AUR(i guess, you use ArchLinux) or author of this program to fix this issue, if it is possible.
I think, it is only way.